# Dealing with spaces of variables for `mv`

Tags: bash, mv

let's say I have a directory with the following files/directories:

```
google
apple
mozilla foundation   # a file with spaces
browsers
```

So I would like to move files into `browsers` directory. Here is a script I wrote:

```
for d in $(ls); do
    if ! [ "$d" == "browsers" ]; then
        mv "$d" "browsers"
    fi
done
```

Then `google` and `apple` went to `browsers` but I got:

```
mv: cannot stat 'mozilla': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'foundation': No such file or directory
```

Obviously, the problem is spaces in a variable. What's the proper way to deal with this?

Of course I believe there should be a more elegant one-line command to do this, but I would like to know how I should use variables with spaces.

Comment: Set `IFS='\n'` before doing your command, but reset it to default value afterwards.

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Answer (score 7):

Do **not** ever use:

```
for d in $(ls)
```

Use this instead:

```
for d in *
```

Two problems, among others, with the use of `$(ls)` are that the shell subjects the results of `$(ls)` to *word splitting* and *pathname expansion*.  In your case, it was *word splitting* that caused  `mozilla foundation` to turn into `mozilla` and `foundation`.

For a lengthier discussion of the reason not to use `$(ls)`, see ["What does `$(ls *.txt)` do?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944801/what-does-ls-txt-do/)

If you need to account for the case where there is no non-hidden file in the directory (the case where `for i in $(ls)` may look better as it doesn't do any pass in the loop as opposed to one pass in the loop with `*` as `$i` in `for i in *` (except in `zsh`)), you'd want to tell the shell to not expand to anything for non-matching globs:

- `zsh`: `for i in *(N)`
- `ksh93`: `for i in ~(N)*`
- `bash4.4+`: `f() { local -; shopt -s nullglob; for i in *; ...; done; }; f` (the point being to use the `nullglob` option locally (see also the `failglob` option for a behaviour similar to `zsh`'s default one)).
- `yash`: `set -o nullglob` (and reset afterwards, there's no local scope for options in `yash` as far as I know)
- in other shells, you can always add a `[ -e "$i" ] || [ -L "$i" ] || continue` in the loop to check for the file's existence.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think that way. Thank you. So is there no way to change `mozilla foundation` to `mozilla\ foundation` or `"mozilla foundation"`?

Comment: @BumsikKim there might be, but why break and reassemble when you can get it unbroken?

Comment: You're welcome.  And, yes, there are many ways to manipulate strings like `mozilla foundation` but, if you use the above `for f in *`, you won't need to manipulate it: it will just work.  Or, were you looking for some other use?

Comment: @John1024 I think that's enough. I was thinking the solution I was looking for might be useful in other potential cases but it was just a wild thought

Comment: @BumsikKim Very good.  Generally, the key is to avoid word splitting in the first place.  (Once a file name is split, you'll never really know how to reassemble --- one space or two or tabs or ...)  Fortunately, there are a variety of good techniques that avoid those pitfalls.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas As always, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

[Do not parse `ls` result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/72456), and beside of John1024's answer you could use `find`.

```
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' -type f -exec mv -t /path/to/dest {} +
```

(here assuming GNU `find` for the `-t` option, skipping hidden files like `ls` or a `*` glob would and excluding non-regular files. Note that the list is not sorted (contrary to with `ls` or `*`). `LC_ALL=C` is needed to properly skip any file whose name starts with `.` even those that don't contain valid characters in the user's locale. That affects the language of error messages though).